# Wrongly git pull and conflicts occur

Tags: git, git-pull

I am facing issue after wrongly use `git pull` command but after that i got conflict issues. But i want to revert that `git pull` and resync my local project with online git project.

help to get solution for this problem.

Comment: Try with git reset --hard or even git checkout <branch>

Comment: Please, put error trace, you got

Answer (score 0):

You got conflicts because your local branch has some commits, that remote branch does not. Now your have options:

### resolve conflicts

resolve conflicts to stay with your local commits as well

1. manually resolve conflicts
2. stage changes with `git add`
3. `git rebase --continue`
4. push local changes to remove with `git push`

### reset local branch

reset local branch to remote state

```
git rebase --abort
git reset --hard origin/your-branch-name
```